# Why can’t I create a file with a name prefixed by “passwd.” in “/etc”?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions

I have a PC with Ubuntu 16.04 installed. Recently I want to install some packages but have trouble installing them. After some digging, I found that the failure seems to be related to the linux user account system. The problem is that any file with a name prefixed by `passwd.` cannot be created in `/etc` path.

```
# ls /etc/passwd.*
ls: cannot access '/etc/passwd.*': No such file or directory

# touch /etc/passwd.test-test-test
touch: cannot touch '/etc/passwd.test-test-test': Permission denied

# ls /etc/passwe.*
ls: cannot access '/etc/passwe.*': No such file or directory

# touch /etc/passwe.test-test-test
#
```

I can create that file in other paths, such as `/` or `/usr`, but not in `/etc`, and I can create file with other file names in `/etc`, but not with file names prefixed by `passwd.`. I can’t reproduce this problem with other PCs.

I have tried other commands:

- `nano /etc/shadow.xxx`
- `echo xxx > /etc/shadow.xxx`
- `touch /etc/test-temp-file && mv /etc/test-temp-file /etc/shadow.xxx`
- `systemctl stop apparmor`
- Reboot the system

Nothing works.

What could cause this problem?

Here are some debug command outputs:

```
# ls -ld /etc
drwxr-xr-x 136 root root 12288 Aug 12 10:07 /etc

# lsattr -d /etc
----------I--e-- /etc

# ls -dZ /etc
? /etc

# type -a touch
touch is /usr/bin/touch
touch is /bin/touch

# file "$(command -v touch)"
/usr/bin/touch: symbolic link to /bin/touch
```

Here is the `strace` output:

```
# strace touch /etc/passwd.test-test-test
execve("/usr/bin/touch", ["touch", "/etc/passwd.test-test-test"], [/* 22 vars */]) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x8da000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=80559, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 80559, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f9bc360e000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P\t\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1868984, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9bc360d000
mmap(NULL, 3971488, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f9bc3033000
mprotect(0x7f9bc31f3000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f9bc33f3000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1c0000) = 0x7f9bc33f3000
mmap(0x7f9bc33f9000, 14752, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9bc33f9000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9bc360c000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9bc360b000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f9bc360c700) = 0
mprotect(0x7f9bc33f3000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x60e000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7f9bc3622000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f9bc360e000, 80559)           = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x8da000
brk(0x8fb000)                           = 0x8fb000
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1668976, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 1668976, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f9bc3473000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/etc/passwd.test-test-test", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK, 0666) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
utimensat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/passwd.test-test-test", NULL, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2995, ...}) = 0
read(3, "# Locale name alias data base.\n#"..., 4096) = 2995
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "touch: ", 7touch: )                  = 7
write(2, "cannot touch '/etc/passwd.test-t"..., 41cannot touch '/etc/passwd.test-test-test') = 41
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, ": Permission denied", 19: Permission denied)     = 19
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Comment: what does `ls -ld /etc` say? How about `lsattr -d /etc`? If you are using SELinux, what does `ls -dZ /etc` say? If you are using AppArmor, what does the equivalent command (I don't know what it is) say? How is this `/etc/` different from the `/etc` on other PCs? Run the same commands there and look for differences.

Comment: Is `touch` a function or a script or something? What do `type -a touch` and `file "$(command -v touch)"` report? I cannot reproduce on my 16.04 box.

Comment: @NickD I have compared all command outputs except for the AppArmor one because I didn’t find how to show the related information of a folder. The result are the same.

Comment: @muru `touch` is the original executable.

Comment: @EFanZh how did you determine that? Did you check the checksums of the `coreutils` package?

Comment: @muru, the `touch` command doesn’t matter. It’s not only touch, I can’t create the file using: `nano`; `echo` then redirect the output using `>` operator; create another file then rename. Nothing works.

Comment: Just to make sure: you're doing this as `root`, right?

Comment: Does `grep passwd /var/log/kern.log /var/log/audit/audit.log` show anything?

Comment: @Panki Yes, I was using `root`. I uses `sudo su` command before any operations.  `id` command prints `uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)`.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I searched all files stored in `/var/log`, the outputs of `dmesg`, and the output of `journalctl --this-boot`, there is nothing notable.

Comment: Ubuntu apparently uses apparmor, see: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppArmor

Comment: What happens if you run `setenforce 0` first? This looks more like an selinux thing than an apparmor thing.

Comment: @RafaelKitover It seems that selinux isn’t installed on my PC.

Comment: @RafaelKitover I also tried `systemctl stop apparmor`, and it does not work.

Comment: Try with `aa-complain /bin/touch; /bin/touch /etc/passwd.test`, then look in the logs. (untested, just based on the info [here](https://linuxhint.com/debian_apparmor_tutorial/)).

Comment: @mosvy `aa-complain` prints `Profile for /bin/touch not found, skipping`.

Comment: try with `/usr/bin/touch`. If nothing works, try booting with `apparmor` disabled -- it should be explained in that link how (sorry I'm not able to test).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found out why. It is because ISecTP (Endpoint Security for Linux Threat Prevention) was installed on my PC. It includes "[Access Protection](https://docs.mcafee.com/bundle/endpoint-security-10.5.1-installation-guide-linux/page/GUID-6435A91D-88E1-4EF6-88E7-2071E6BAAEC3.html)", which uses either the fanotify kernel interface, or injection of a custom module into the kernel ([configurable which of these it does](https://docs.mcafee.com/bundle/endpoint-security-10.5.1-installation-guide-linux/page/GUID-D3601C81-2098-4BC3-A5F2-7E3E53A4D555.html)), to cause accesses to arbitrary paths to be denied. I wasn’t aware of it because I’m not the only one who uses the PC. After uninstalling it, everything is fine now.

Thank you, everyone, for your help!

Comment: Very interesting, I have never heard of software like this, as far as I knew everyone was using either selinux or apparmor.

Comment: Thank you for providing an update. When you can, please accept your own answer.